# Occasional 422 error: client not sending session cookie?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A few users are getting a `422 ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error when POSTing a form.

It happens to a minority of users some of the time. If they try their request again later, it often works.

The authenticity token is getting sent along in every case. I'm assuming the client isn't sending the session cookie along with the POST (that would explain why the server can't verify the token). Why would this be?

Finally, the form is submitted via javascript (`$('#new_user')[0].submit()`), would that somehow prevent the session cookie from being sent?

Disabling the `verify_authenticity_token` before_filter is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: It seems like your controller still need auth token. digg deeper

Answer (score 1):

We have run into this scenario with one of our apps. We store our sessions in memcached and if the session is evicted from the cache or the session expires any subsequent post/put/delete raised a 422. We got round this by implementing a before filter 'requires_login?' that checked the session and logout the user out if the session had expired. We then moved the method protect_from_forgery in the application controller to run after requires_login?

E.G

```
before_filter :requires_login?

protect_from_forgery
```

Hope this makes sense

Comment: You can do this: protect_from_forgery with: :reset_session instead of a separate method. We did reset_session and a longer memcache life on our session keys, this seems to have stopped the 422's in general.